# Is there a name for a neither-increasing-nor-decreasing-but-alternating sequence like below?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

A sequence of at least two distinct integers ${ \left\{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, \ldots, x_n | n \geq 2, x_i \ne x_j \forall i \ne j \right\} }$ that satisfies either the property:
$$
x_1 < x_2 > x_3 < x_4 \cdots <> x_n
$$

or:

$$
x_1 > x_2 < x_3 > x_4 \cdots <> x_n
$$

Is there a name for such a sequence?

Given any sequence of distinct integers, it is possible to arrange (or, "sort") it to satisfy the above property.

Positive integers can be arranged like http://oeis.org/A065190 or http://oeis.org/A103889.

The "sorted" arrangements of $\{ 1, 2 \}$ is: $1 > 2$ and $2 > 1$.
The "sorted" arrangements of $\{ 1, 2, 3 \}$ is: $1 < 3 > 2$ and $3 > 1 < 2$, and their mirrors: $2 < 3 > 1$ and $2 > 1 < 3$.

How many such (mirrored and non-mirrored) arrangements are possible?

Are there any other properties of such sequences?

Comment: That would just be an alternating sequence. At least, if you substract the mean, it literally is an alternating sequence.

Comment: When $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are a permutation of the numbers $1,\dots,n$, they are sometimes called *up-down* and *down-up* permutations, respectively.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: I would normally understand *alternating sequence* to be one whose terms alternated in sign.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, but you could see it as the sum of a constant sequence and an alternating sequence.

Comment: As with @Brian, I've heard them called "up-down permutations". Wikipedia seems to give priority to the term "alternating permutation": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation . As mentioned there, $\sec\theta+\tan\theta$ is the exponential generating function of the associated "Euler up-down (or zig-zag) numbers". (Not mentioned there, though, is that the connection between combinatorics and analytics is actually ... um ... geometrics. See my note "Zig-Zag Involutes, Up-Down Permutations, and Secant and Tangent":  http://dlnds.com/math/pdfs/sectan.pdf )

Comment: @Raskolnikov: I can't see $1325476$ as the sum of a constant sequence and a sequence whose terms alternate in sign.

Comment: @Rahul: You're right, I didn't think that through. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn’t really matter what $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are, as long as they are distinct, so let’s take them to be $1,\dots,n$. These permutations are called *zigzag permutations*. A permutation of your first kind is an *up-down permutation* or an *alternating permutation*; one of your second kind is a *down-up permutation*.

It’s not hard to see that there are exactly as many up-down permutations as there are down-up permutations. If $\pi$ be a zigzag permutation of $1,\dots,n$, let $\hat\pi$ be the permutation obtained by changing each term $x$ into $n+1-x$. For example, if $n=5$ and $\pi=32514$, $\hat\pi=34152$. If $\pi$ is up-down, $\hat\pi$ is down-up, and if $\pi$ is down-up, $\hat\pi$ is up-down, so this bijectively pairs up the two kinds of zigzag permutations.

The number of up-down permutations of $1,\dots,n$ is often denoted by $A_n$; these numbers have been called the *Euler zigzag numbers* and the *up-down numbers*. To get the total number of zigzag permutations of $1,\dots,n$, just double $A_n$. As you’ve discovered, $A_2=1$ and $A_3=2$. The next few values are $A_4=5$, $A_5=16$, and $A_6=61$. These numbers are sequence [A000111](http://oeis.org/A000111) in the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/wiki/Welcome). To the best of my knowledge thay have no nice closed form; a rather ugly formula for $A_n$ is derived [here](https://oeis.org/A000111/a000111.pdf) [PDF].

You can read more about them [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation).

Comment: Thanks @Brian! From the Wikipedia link, I found the additional terms "fence" and "zigzag poset".

Comment: The link in “... is derived here” seems to be broken.

Comment: @MartinR: Fortunately, it turns out that the paper can now by found at OEIS, and I’ve updated the link.